# Increment id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox which is a div that changes class if it's clicked. It starts with `check unchecked` as class. If it's clicked, we add the `checked` class to change background.

I added an id to this div; it starts with `check0` until `check(number of my data)`.
This div contains another div which has text like `picture` and is identified by `check_txt0` until `check_txt(number of my data)`.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".check").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

So, I want to get the `check_txt(i)` value; I added this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".check").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                if ($('#check' + i).hasClass("checked")) {
                    var resultat = $('#check_txt' + i).val();
                    alert(resultat);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it alerts nothing and doesn't alert when I click it the first time. It only does it when I reclick for the second. It's probably because it doesn't recognize the `checked` class on the first click.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BGQzm/2/

Comment: why don't you jsfiddle it?

Comment: Why don't you combine the functionality to make sure they run in the correct order.

Comment: you should post the relevant html too

Comment: Like Joao Palma said put some Html i am kind confuse with class .check and id #check maybe changing those name for something more relevant.

Comment: i added jsfiddle on my post

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BGQzm/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your code don't have any problem its the way you put priority on your code its should be  this one to be call above

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".check").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

This one after and everything work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".check").click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("checked")){
        for(i=0;i<40;i++){
        if($('#check'+i).hasClass("checked")){
        var resultat = $('#check_txt'+i).html();
        var data = 'motclef=' + resultat;
        alert(resultat);
        }
        }


        }

     });


});
```

Comment: but it doesn't alert pic or illus

Comment: replace $('#check_txt'+i).val(); for $('#check_txt'+i).html(); I just edit code above

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.check', function(event) {
     var target = event.target;

     if($(target).prop('checked',true)){
       alert($(target).val());
     }

});
```

Comment: i wanna check_txt val not check val

Answer (score 0):

Have the results-getting-bit called after the class has changed, like this:

```
function getResults() {
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        if ($('#check' + i).hasClass("checked")) {
            var resultat = $('#check_txt' + i).val();
            alert(resultat);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".check").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
            getResults();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }
        // or call getResults() here instead if you want it to happen whether the box was checked or unchecked.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the ancient jsfiddle; 
their is the newest:
http://jsfiddle.net/bnDeK/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".check").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("checked")){
    for(i=0;i<40;i++){
    if($('#check'+i).hasClass("checked")){
    var resultat = $('#check_txt'+i).val();
    var data = 'motclef=' + resultat;
    alert(resultat);
    }
    }


    }

 });
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".check").click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
    $(this).removeClass("checked");
}
else {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
}
});

});
```